# Please show me how to approach and solve the problem: Find the minimum value of $ f(x)=x^{2}-4x+3+3\cos(\frac{\pi x}{4})$

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

Problem: Find the minimum value of $ f(x)=x^{2}-4x+3+3\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)$

---

At first, I found the minimum value of each functions $g(x)=x^{2}-4x+3$ and 
$h(x)=3\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)$ but they do not happen at the same  value of $x$.

Then, I use the derivation of $f(x)$ to find the exact value of $x$.
$f'(x)=2x-4-3\frac{\pi }{4}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)$.
 At this step, i found it difficult to solve it because of the complicated function.
 Although I mean to use the graph of the derivation, I think it is still hard.

---

Please help me to find some approaches that are suitable to high school's curricula. Thank you!

Comment: Show us how you used the derivative and we will be able to explain where you may have gone wrong

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange! Please edit your question and show some more work, you've mentioned you computed the derivative, so show it here! Also, know that some equations require numerical rather than analytic solutions, a simple method for finding such numerical solutions is [Newton–Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

Comment: To me it looks like you've done some error. I find that $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ both takes minimal value for $x=2$

Comment: @skyking $h(x)$ is [not minimal at $x=2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minima+3cos%28%28pi+x%29%2F4%29), how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @lioness99a By misreading the argument to $\cos$;)

Comment: @lioness99a  I have just edited it, but I do not think It will help us much

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the function is

$$2x-4-\frac{3\pi}4\sin\frac{\pi x}4.$$

This is indeed a transcendental function for which there is no "easy" root, and you can bet that that it cannot be solved analytically.

Numerically, $x\approx2.8973954310014$ is the only solution, corresponding to a minimum.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any ideas for this problem? Please show us!

Comment: @AnhTuấnTrầnNguyễn: do you consider my answer as void ??

Comment: I do not mean to say that, I just want to know how to solve the problem by some ways helpful.

Comment: @AnhTuấnTrầnNguyễn: what do you know about numerical methods ?

Comment: Sorry, I have not learnt it yet.

Comment: @AnhTuấnTrầnNguyễn: then either there is a typo in the question, or this question is not for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the derivative, by inspection or plotting, we can see that the solution is close to $x=3$.

So, make a Taylor expansion to get for
$$y=2 x-\frac{3}{4} \pi  \sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{4}\right)-4$$ $$y=\left(2-\frac{3 \pi }{4 \sqrt{2}}\right)+\left(2+\frac{3 \pi ^2}{16
   \sqrt{2}}\right) (x-3)+\frac{3 \pi ^3 }{128 \sqrt{2}}(x-3)^2+O\left((x-3)^3\right)$$ Now, using series reversion  to obtain
$$x=3+t-\frac{3 \pi ^3 }{256 \sqrt{2}+24 \pi ^2}t^2+O\left(t^5\right)\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\frac{4 \left(8 (y-2)+3 \sqrt{2} \pi \right)}{64+3 \sqrt{2} \pi ^2}$$ Making $y=0$, an *approximation* is $x=2.897492$ while the exact solution, given by @Yves Daoust, is                   $x=2.897395$.

**Edit**

We can have a quite good *approxiamtion* of the solution using the approximation
$$\sin(t) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -t) t}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -t) t}\qquad (0\leq t\leq\pi)$$ was proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician.

Using it, after simplifications, we end with a cubic equation 
$$2 x^3-3(4- \pi ) x^2+4(14-3 \pi ) x-80=0$$ the real solution of which being
$$x=2+\sqrt{\frac{64}{3}-\pi ^2} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3} \pi  \left(56-\pi ^2\right)}{\left(64-3 \pi
   ^2\right)^{3/2}}\right)\right)-\frac{\pi }{2}\approx 2.89641$$ This vaue would give a minimum value of $f(x)$ equal to $-2.13835345$ while a rigorous calculations lead to  $-2.13835500$